# Orientation induced on tangent plane

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, tangent-spaces

Being $S $ a oriented surface and $\mathcal {O} $ the orientation, each $\psi\in\mathcal {O} $ induces a orientation on $T_pS $ by the basis $\psi_u,\psi_v $.

I need to prove that this not depends of parametrization.

I am confused about the determinant of changing basis. This is a them that always confused on my mind.

Is correct this?

> $(\psi_\tilde {u},\psi_\tilde {v})=    \det J (\psi^{-1}○\varphi)(p)(\varphi_u,\varphi_v) $.

Is this the ***matrix to changing coordinates on tangent plane***? If yes or not, could you, please, explain a little bit about this?

In fact, I am understanding the concepts of differential geomtry, but when I have to do the thing by my own, I am with a lot of difficulties.

Many thanks.

Comment: What is your definition of an orientation on $S$?

Comment: It has an atlas s.t. two neighborhoods are disjunt or the changing of parameterization has positive Jacobian. Many thanks